# First error: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 1; first error: INVALID_STATUS, invalid convertedStatus: Qualified: [Status]

Tags: soql, scheduled-apex

I am getting this error from following batch apex class.

```
global class SL_Batch_Match_LeadsWithAccounts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    public static set<Id> OppAcctIds;
    //Map<ID, Account> acctMap = new Map<ID, Account>();
    List<Account> acctsList;
    public static List <Opportunity> oppListToUpdateFlag;
    String leadRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Sun Homes - LPS').getRecordTypeId();
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query = 'Select AccountId, Flag__c from Opportunity where Flag__c = \'New\'';// And RecordTypeId ='+'\''+leadRecordTypeId+'\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject>scope){
        //OppAcctIds = new set<Id>();
        //acctsList = new List <Account>();
        oppListToUpdateFlag = new List<Opportunity>();
        List <String> acctAndLeadIdList = new List <String>();
        for(Sobject s : scope){
            Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)s;

            //OppAcctIds.add(opp.AccountId);
            oppListToUpdateFlag.add(opp);
            Map<ID, Account> acctMap = new Map<ID, Account>([Select Name, Phone, PersonEmail From Account Where ID =: opp.AccountId]);
            for(ID acctID :acctMap.keySet()){
                if(opp.AccountID == acctID){

                    Map<ID, Lead> leadMap = new Map<ID, Lead>([Select IsConverted from Lead Where Name =:acctMap.get(acctID).Name AND (Phone =:acctMap.get(acctID).Phone OR Email=:acctMap.get(acctID).PersonEmail)]);
                    for(ID leadID :leadMap.keySet()){
                        if(leadID != null && !leadMap.get(leadID).IsConverted){
                            String temp =  acctID + '-' +leadID;
                            acctAndLeadIdList.add(temp);
                            //mergLeadWithExistingAccount(acctID,leadID);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(!acctAndLeadIdList.isEmpty()){
            mergLeadWithExistingAccount(acctAndLeadIdList);
        }
        if(!oppListToUpdateFlag.isEmpty()){
            updateOpportuniyFlags(oppListToUpdateFlag);
        }

    }

    public void mergLeadWithExistingAccount(List <String> acctAndLeadIdListRecieved){
        list<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new list<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(String acctAndLeadId: acctAndLeadIdListRecieved){
            String tempAcctId = acctAndLeadId.substringBefore('-');
            String tempLeadId = acctAndLeadId.substringAfter('-');
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(tempLeadId);
            lc.setAccountId(tempAcctId);
            //LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
            //lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
            lc.setConvertedStatus('Qualified');
            //lc.convertedStatus = 'Qualified';
            //Database.ConvertLead(lc,true);
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
            leadConverts.add(lc);
        }
        List <Database.LeadConvertResult> results = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
        for(Integer i=0; i <= results.size(); i++){
        System.assert(results[i].isSuccess());
        }
        System.debug(results);
    }
    public void updateOpportuniyFlags(List<Opportunity> oppList){
        List<Opportunity> tempOppList = new List<Opportunity>();

        for (Opportunity opp: oppList){
            opp.Flag__c = 'Processed';
            tempOppList.add(opp);
        }
        update tempOppList;
    }
    /*public void matchLeadWithAccount(Lead leadRecievedForMatching){
        for (Account acc: [Select id from Account where Name=:leadRecievedForMatching.Name AND (PersonEmail =:leadRecievedForMatching.Email OR  Phone=:leadRecievedForMatching.Phone)]){
            if (acc.id != Null){
                //mergLeadWithExistingAccount(acc.id,leadRecievedForMatching);
            }
        }
    }*/
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

I also have the converted value checked for this status.
Thanks in Advance.
[image: Picture is showing that both values are checked]

Here is the snip of screen while converting lead manually.
[image]

Comment: check converted checkbox is true for this LeadStatus.

Comment: @TusharSharma please read the last line of my question. I have cleared that its checked.

Comment: Message is pretty clear. The status you are adding is not one you can set a converted lead to. You need to query leadstatus for records that are isconvertedstatus and use one of those

Comment: @Eric I used the below code
`LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
   lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);`
and still get following error.
`First error: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_STATUS, invalid convertedStatus: Booked: [Status]`

Comment: @TanveerAhmad is that status active ?

Comment: @Eric it's also active.

Comment: I have attached the snipe. You can see

Comment: Shot in the dark then: 1. Are you using record types? Is that status available for that record type? 2: Any chance the lead is already converted

Comment: Yes I am using Record types and status is available for that record type. You can see the last snip of this question. It clearly shows that its available while converting the Lead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be due to the Status' not being available for the record types the user has access to / assigned to the lead:

> Record types: If the organization uses record types, the default
>   record type of the new owner is assigned to records created during
>   lead conversion.
>
> The default record type of the user converting the lead determines the
>   lead source values available during conversion. If the desired lead
>   source values are not available, add the values to the default record
>   type of the user converting the lead.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_convertlead.htm

Since everything else checks out this seems to be the only thing left....

Comment: I have added a snip. Please check it out.

Comment: Could you please review the code? It is not working for more than one record and not updating the opportunities.

Answer (score 4):

after another API version update there is a new field representing closing status. instead of `MasterLabel` you should use `ApiName`, they may differ.

so the code snippet inside `mergLeadWithExistingAccount()` method should look like:

```
LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, ApiName FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.ApiName);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the case - specially if MasterLabel and ApiName differ. Using MasterLabel to set the status causes the code to fail. To avoid any potential issues, use ApiName.