# Should we use MasterLabel or API name for Lead Statuses while converting a Lead

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I was working an issue reported while converting a lead on a customer org which was throwing  an **Invalid Status** error which i had asked about in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191693/invalid-convertedstatus) thread.

Referring to code in documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm)

```
Lead myLead = new Lead(LastName = 'Fry', Company='Fry And Sons');
insert myLead;

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

They are using MasterLabel for setting the status while conversion. In one of our customer org they had the api name different from the Masterlabel and while i was passing the MasterLabel it always threw a **invalid status** error. Once i had the api name and Master label as same the error disappeared. So is it best to use api name instead or MasterLabel?

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, you should use the **API Name**. Using the masterLabel will throw an exception at runtime. The only exception would be if the masterLabel and apiName are the same (typically when the status is a single word), but this isn't something you can rely on.

Comment: Just something to be aware of, your code needs to be running in API v36.0 or later in order to use the ApiName field.  Older code will certainly need amending **and** changing to API v36.0 or later.